# How to show search by company name, but only show the first name and last name?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

This is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // List view
    private AutoCompleteTextView lv;

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;



    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Listview Data
       /* String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE",
                                "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800",
                                "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};*/
        User p = null;

        p = new User("1", "Starhub Pte Ltd","Manager","Jason", "Bourne","");
        userList.add(p);      
        p = new User("2", "Singtel Pte Ltd", "Senior Manager","Ben", "Chia","");
        userList.add(p);  
        p = new User("3", "Ngee Ann Polytechnic", "Senior lecturer","Charles", "Xavier","");
        userList.add(p); 
        p = new User("4", "Dreamcity Pte Ltd", "","Ben", "Chia","");
        userList.add(p); 
        p = new User("5", "DBS Corporation", "Secretary","Michelle", "Chong","");
        userList.add(p); 
        p = new User("6", "OCBC bank", "Deputy finance Manager","YongZheng", "Wong","");
        userList.add(p); 

        AutoCompleteTextView lv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView); // NOTE: change to your autocomplete textview id

        // Adding items to listview

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, getUsernames(userList));
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);  



    }

    private ArrayList<String> getUsernames(ArrayList<User> users)
    {
        ArrayList<String> usernames = new ArrayList<String>();


        for(User u : users)

        {
            usernames.add(u.getFirstName() +" "+ u.getLastName() +" "+ u.getCompanyName()); 

        }

        return usernames;
    }
}
```

Anyway to just return the firstname and lastname, but hide the company name? please advise. Currently I can either return everything, or only can search by firstname and lastname only.............................................

Comment: Did I misunderstand? Why you are not just doing this? `usernames.add(u.getFirstName() +" "+ u.getLastName() ); `

Also I didn't see anything about searching in your code, what do you mean?

Comment: You want your autocomplete dialog to search using the company name without showing it? Or you just want to ignore it letting the user to type just the name or the surname? In the second case the comment by @GokhanArik will work just fine.

Comment: I mean search the user by it company name

Comment: I need to get the firstname and lastname by just typing the company name

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully understood your question, but did you mean searching through the users by company tag? If this is the case then see the following method:

```
private ArrayList<String> getUsernames(ArrayList<User> users, String company_name)
{
    ArrayList<String> usernames = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(User u : users)
    {
        if (u.getCompanyName().equals(company_name))
            usernames.add(u.getFirstName() +" "+ u.getLastName());
    }

    return usernames;
}
```

I have changed the method parameters. "getUsernames" method now takes "company_name" variable which goes to the foreach loop and finds those users corresponding to that company. Hope it helps.

Comment: How shld I change here? adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, getUsernames(userList, companyname)